# Copy contents of "cells" to another cell with increments

Tags: jquery

I've got a table which has a button to add a new row.  When this new row is added, the field RS_Staff_Title1 becomes incremented to RS_Staff_Title2 and so on.  What this button also does is adds a row to another table.

I've then got this function to copy the contents of RS_Staff_Title1 into a field on this other table as you type.

```
$("#RS_Staff_Title1").keyup(function() {
        var value = $(this).val()
        $("p").text(value);
    }).keyup();
```

What I need to achieve though is for any content in RS_Staff_Title1 on StaffTable to be copied into RS_Staff_Title1 on ResourceTable and so on for however many increments are made

UPDATE:

My HTML for the row in the Staff table is:

```
<tr>
<td><input id="RS_Staff_Title1" name="RS_Staff_Title1" style="width:100%;"></td>
```

The JS to add a row to both tables is:

```
$("#add_row").click(function() {
    var row = $("#staff tbody > tr:last"),
        newRow = row.clone(true);
    newRow.find("input").each(function() {
        var num = +(this.id.match(/\d+$/) || [0])[0] + 1;
        this.id = this.id.replace(/\d+$/, "") + num;
        this.name = this.id;
    });
    newRow.insertAfter(row);
    return false;
});
$("#add_row").click(function() {
    var row = $("#resource-cost tbody > tr:last"),
        newRow = row.clone(true);
    newRow.find("input").each(function() {
        var num = +(this.id.match(/\d+$/) || [0])[0] + 1;
        this.id = this.id.replace(/\d+$/, "") + num;
        this.name = this.id;
    });
    newRow.insertAfter(row);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to not bind `keyup` event for every new row you can use `.live` (`.on` in latest jQuery) to add it only once and make it work for any new items added. Besides, ID must be unique and you can't have two elements with ID RS_Staff_TitleN. 
I would place a class on RS_Staff_Title elements and bind keyup handler like this:

```
$(document).on("keyup", ".StaffTableTitle", function() {
    var value = $(this).val()
    var id = $(this).data("rowindex");
    $(".ResourceTableTitle #RT_Staff_Title" + id + " p").text(value);
});
```

RT_Staff_Title - suggested ID for RS_StaffTitle in ResourceTable in order to have unique IDs

`.data("rowindex");` should be set like this `.data("rowindex", index)` for newly added rs_staff_title element when you create it (just easier to get it from there than from ID and it is needed to find corresponding element in ResourceTable later)

```
newRow.find("input").each(function() {
        var num = +(this.id.match(/\d+$/) || [0])[0] + 1;
        this.id = this.id.replace(/\d+$/, "") + num;
        $(this).data("rowindex", num);
        this.name = this.id;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think i've got it correct, however I'm a little confused over the rowindex part.  How does it know to take the contents of RS_Staff_TitleN and copy it to its equivalent in the resource table

Comment: `$(this)` is a pointer to RS_Staff_TitleN. When you create new RS_Staff_Title element you already has N which is rowindex (in my code). You should set that value for newly created element like this: `.data("rowindex", N)` and later, when event happens you can get it with `$(this).data('rowindex')`

Comment: I've added the code on how im adding the new rows and the HTML for the row I wish to take it from.  Maybe i've not explained myself very well